# isTextPresent using text with accents in Selenium RC

Tags: encoding, selenium, selenium-rc, selenium-ide

I have some tests that I need to maintain for the Selenium RC. They are testing isTextPresent passing some text with accents and this is always resulting false (even when the text is present). The same tests run normally in the Selenium IDE.
I have something like this:

```
assertTrue(selenium.isTextPresent("exact:Você tem certeza que deseja realizar a exclusão?"));
```

I think it's a encoding problem. Maybe the Selenium RC is not recognizing the the UTF-8 characteres.

Can someone help me? Thanks in advance.

---

Edit:

I found that the problem is with the browser that the Selenium RC starts during the tests. The message that I'm searching for the presence appears normally with the firefox and the chrome, but the characters with accents appear strange in the firefox started by the Selenium RC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an open issue about this: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=1212
And it has a low priority, since the development team is focusing in the WebDriver.

So, I'm gonna migrate all my tests to WebDriver.